# Using just xxhdpi-size icons for Android

Tags: android

Currently, all my icons (32x32) are stored in drawable-mdpi directory. Android seems to be doing a good job of resizing it appropriately for small phones to 21" tablets.

I am wondering if it would be better to use 96x96 icons in xxhdpi directory instead. I am thinking downsizing of image will maintain better quality than upsizing.

Comment: What is the question? If that is a good idea? Why not just place the images in the `drawable` folder in that case? Might work mostly, but sometimes scaled images look blurry.

Comment: My understanding was that the runtime does not resize images in drawable directory.

Comment: Yes, it would be better. Scaling works best "down" than "up", because it can remove details by interpolation, while it can't INVENT details where there aren't. Also note that in xxhdpi folder the 96*96 px image should have a resolution of 480 dpi, not the standard 72 dpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have fairly simple icons with not a lot of detail, then the resampling of the image to lower or higher resolutions shouldn't produce any visible artifacts. The reason you would have the same image at multiple resolutions and dpi levels is so that you know exactly what the icon will look like. You'll find with complex images the results can be unwanted if you just use one resolution and leave it up to OS to resample it.

Here's a great example of what can happen if you take a complex 512x512 image and downsample it to 16x16. While this case might be exaggerated, you'll find the 32x32 icon won't be much better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case, the artist has given us higher-resolution png images. My thought was either I resize them for each display size or let Android do the magic.